# Issue with duplicate search results and XMLParser array refresh

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsxmlparser, uisearchbar

I use an NSXMLParser to parse ext. API data. I also use a Singleton shared array var to maintain info retrieved from ext API.

This info is dynamic and changesas the user types anything in UISearchBar

Now the thing is as soon as the user types anything, I clear off the existing array contents by using     [retrievedArray removeAllObjects];

Thus this refreshed retrievedArray based on the current terms in the search bar.

This works fine if the user types slowly. However I get to see duplicate search results if the user types very fast. This, I am assuming, is because the retrievedArray contents do not get enough time to clear off.

*I am still trying to resolve the issue. Please suggest some more fixes.*

Could you please provide me the fix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, I don't think this is the case, unless you're doing search in a separate thread and clear array in another one. If not, then there is probably error in your search logic.

Comment: @Max Yes, I use a thread

NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
    [self setURL: url];
 NSThread* myThread = [[NSThread alloc] initWithTarget:self
                                                 selector:@selector(run:)
               object: nil];
    [retrievedArray removeAllObjects];
 [myThread start];
    [pool release];

I even tried without the thread but still the issue persists on fast typing. 
Could you please suggest any other fix .

Comment: No, using threads is ok, you just have to use @synchronize(retrievedArray) {} every time you are accessing your array.

Comment: I can suggest you a little trick: define the method -(void) clearArray { @synchronized(retrieveArray) { [retrievedArray removeAllObjects]; } } and another one, i.e. -(void) appendArray { //populate array with data here  }     Put NSLog in that methods, where you can print the array size. And you will see when it is changing. You can also print the tread id.

Comment: Another solution is to change your retrievedArray type from NSMutableArray to NSMutableSet. This would prevent duplicate results. But this is the bed solution because it fixes only symptoms and not the real cause.

Comment: @Max...I am trying to implement your solution...but needed some more clarity on how to go about it.  When you say "you just have to use @synchronize(retrievedArray) {} every time you are accessing your array" ...Is it to be used in the definition OR everywhere I have retrievedArray...Could you please provide me the exact syntax. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Max Not sure if Max got notified of the above comment ?

Comment: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Articles/ocThreading.html

Answer (score 0):

First of all I think a singleton approach may not be the best way to go for what you are doing. But make sure that you are synchronizing all mutable access to the array. Instead of allowing the singleton to return a `NSMutableArray` for any object and their mom (`super`) to use you need to have methods like `addObject`,`removeObject`,`clear` with `@synchronize` blocks or any kind of lock you decide on. I still see issues with this approach because the code calling addObject, remove and clear will all need to be synchronized as well. Maybe consider on each auto complete request you use a delegate or post a `NSNotification` containing a timestamp, the characters the user typed to get data, and a `NSArray` of results. At that time you can see if the response is still valid, discard any invalid responses, and update the user with just the contents of the most recent valid `NSArray`